# PHP: uploading file without file upload control

Tags: php, mysql, file-upload

Using PHP, I want to upload an image that exists on my computer but, without using the file upload control. I just want to click submit which will automatically take the file from the computer and upload it to the database on the server.

Is it possible? If yes, please tell me how.

Comment: http://www.howtogeek.com/169139/sandboxes-explained-how-theyre-already-protecting-you-and-how-to-sandbox-any-program/

Comment: Hi, I see you are trying to say that I should cerate an application which will call the applet and php website within an application, but how that helps here in this problem, that I could not figure out.

Comment: I should have explained that a little better. Anyway, what I was trying to point out, is not the solution, but why what you are trying is not working. It has to do with a browser sandboxing everything a website does, so that it cannot get into the file system of the operating system. This would be very bad security wise. This is only possible if the user grants access to these files using a file uploader.

Answer (score 0):

No it is not possible. System cannot take the file automatically unless the user acts.

Comment: can we place a file upload control with a fixed file path, keep it hidden and then on submit click use this file?

Comment: I am trying to create a fingerprint based authentication mechanism. Java applet reads image on client and saves it on local machine. On clicking verify button, I need this print to be uploaded to server for checking.

Comment: Ok. But you need to save to server as soon as applet reads the image then probably after successful validation you can remove or save .

Comment: I got a ready applet for the device which I cannot alter. so the plan was to save the image on local machine and then it upload via php. Now to keep things easy for the user, looking to auto upload rather than forcing a manual upload.